# toggle in jQuery, hide paragraph in first

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, display

As I mention this in the title in found a jQuery function to create a button which hide and show a paragraph html but, when i go on my page I want my pragraph to be hidden, Now i have the inverse.. the paragraph is display from the beginning

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
<body>
    <button>Toggle between hiding and showing the paragraphs</button>
 <p>
   If you see me it is that you had to click on the button
</p>
</body>
```

Comment: You could simply hide it with CSS `p{ display: none; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just apply `hidden` attribute, to hide that paragraph **by default**.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("p").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Toggle between hiding and showing the paragraphs</button>
<p hidden>
  If you see me it is that you had to click on the button
</p>
```

Comment: That's not an option I would recommend, since it's not supported in IE10 and below. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden

Comment: @blex Few years ago I would agree with you.

Comment: Yes, maybe I'm worrying too much, but I always try to support the widest range of browsers when it's that simple... Anyway, that's still a good solution for modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) the click event handler after its definition.

```js
$("button").click(function(){
    $("p").toggle();
}).trigger('click');
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button>Toggle between hiding and showing the paragraphs</button>
<p>
    If you see me it is that you had to click on the button
</p>
```